# Which one is correct, has been or was?

Tags: word-choice, tense

This mineral has been discovered recently.

This mineral was discovered recently.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. You can use either one, depending on the context you are in.

> This mineral has been discovered recently.

"has been" is in the present perfect tense. The present perfect can be used to "show the present result of a past action".

While the "time of the action is before now", "we are often more interested in the result than in the action itself". More uses [here](https://www.ef.sg/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/).

> This mineral was discovered recently.

"was" is in the past tense. It refers to the past, when the mineral was discovered.